# Fully qualified names of all classes in object hierachy for a given instance

Tags: java, class, object

How to get all object classes in some class.

for example :

```
class ex{
   Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
   void test(){
      String out=in.nextLine();
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,out);
   }
}

class ex2{
   void test(){
      java.io.BufferedReader in = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(System.in));
      String output=in.readLine();
   }
}
```

from this class i want to print out

```
class ex :
java.util.Scanner
java.lang.String
javax.swing.JOptionPane

class ex2 :
java.io.BufferedReader
java.io.InputStreamReader
java.lang.String
```

Comment: That's not going to be easy at all, and I don't think you'll be able to do it from a class that's already loaded in-memory.

Comment: For what purpose? All you have to do is read the import statements.

Comment: i want to create learning program fro identified object class from a class. it's not good idea if my program read import statement, 
how if a class not use import ???

Answer (score 1):

One possible way can be to read your own java class file source from your own class and list out all classes used in your java class

Answer (score 1):

Not possible as you are trying to print the **names of all imported classes** inside the class of the instance what you have in your hand. Think about some classes that have imported to the class file, but the usage of that class(imported classes) will be in restricted scope.(`private` : *The private modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed in its own class.*) Unless you read the class file as in you read a text file and grab the imported class file names.(that may not be a practical solution)

If you want the hierarchy, you can do something like below.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,out.getClass());
```

[More details](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29)

```
public static String printx(Object obj, String output){
    String str2 = new String(obj.getClass().toString());
    if(!str2.equalsIgnoreCase("class java.lang.Object") && !str2.equalsIgnoreCase("class java.lang.Class")){
        output += printx(obj.getClass().getSuperclass(),output);
    }
    output += (","+str2);
    return output;
}
public static void main(String[]args){
          Scanner c = new Scanner(System.in);
          String elzz = printx(c,"");
          elzz = elzz.substring(1);
          System.out.println(elzz);
}
```

Comment: your code cannot apply if class in another directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ASM library to read the class file. The documentation is [here](http://asm.ow2.org/asm33/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassReader.html). You can google some examples as well. Basically you need to read the Class entries of the class constant pool.